# Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

Im getting this error when I try to import any repos mainly from Spring Initializer. I'm behind a proxy but I have my proxies specified so not sure why this is failing. I have tried to run  mvn dependency:purge-local-repository from Stackflow thread but this hasnt helped. I'm using java version "1.8.0_231". The error connection timed out usually points to proxy issues but I have tested and its working for almost everything else except IntelliJ and Eclipse.

*Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.2.4.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/151.101.16.215] failed: Connection timed out: connect*

Comment: Can you build from OS terminal? Sounds like you need to configure Maven for the proxy. Check e.g. https://developers.perfectomobile.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=31103886

Comment: @Andrey I have tried to edit settings.xml and manually added our proxy settings but this has not helped.

Answer (score 1):

check your `IDEA's maven setting`

> Preferences -> Build,Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Maven

is right.
pay close attention to the setting of `User settings file` and `Local repository`. make sure that they match your local settings.